# Sharing Windows 7 Hard drive with Windows XP Hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, networking, file-sharing

I wish to share my hard drives between my two computers but I seem to be running along some sort of error... my windows XP Computer is picking up my "XGaming" hard drive but when clicked it says access is denied, despite there is no password set up(I followed this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/)

I also tried to share my C and J drives on my windows XP computer but my windows 7 computer doesn't seem to even detect them!

Comment: If you did the network driver in XP and did not use any passwords and trying to map it in win 7 you might be out of luck with the passwords sknce win 7 does not like that

Answer (score 0):

Sharing and security are different things so please make sure (For testing purposes) you right click the folder you want to share and select properties, then the sharing tab and set it up for everyone.

Then, click on the security tab and add everyone to your permissions with full rights. If this works, then tweak the security level appropriately.

Comment: They are set up for everyone on both computers...what services need to be on for this to work correctly? I feel like it has something to do with that because this used to function properly in the past until I had turned off some services

Comment: It now sounds like a firewall is stopping it. Or an internet security style program.

Answer (score 0):

File sharing in windows can be a challenging setup. It's easy for things to stop working with firewall software, or differences between windows versions.

Here is a guide/posting that helped me:
http://www.broadbandreports.com/forum/remark,26689267.

Pay attention to the section that begins with "In Network and Sharing Center, click "Choose homegroup "